# Improper sizing using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use a GridBagLayout to have a JFrame that contains a JPanel that has a grid layout and a JPanel with just a large button.  I want the rows to all be the same size, and the JPanel with the JButton to be the same size as one row.  However, the button panel, which is currently empty, is about 1/3 of the JFrame.  I'm not quite sure what's happening, but it is pretty important to me that I maintain this structure because the rest of my code uses this.  Any help is appreciated, and thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Minesweeper extends JPanel {
        private final int SIZE = 7;

        public void startGame(){
                JFrame holder = new JFrame();
                JPanel window = new JPanel();
                JPanel pan = new JPanel();
                holder.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();
                con.weightx = 1;
                con.weighty = 1;
                con.gridx = 0;
                con.gridy = 0;
                con.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                con.gridheight = SIZE;
                con.gridwidth = SIZE;
                holder.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                holder.setSize(450, 450);
                holder.setResizable(false);
                holder.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                window.setLayout(new GridLayout(SIZE, SIZE));
                for (int c=0; c<(SIZE*SIZE); c++){
                        int row = (c/SIZE);
                        int col = (c%SIZE);
                        JPanel p = new JPanel();
                        p.setBackground(Color.gray);
                        Border b = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);
                        p.setBorder(b);
                        window.add(p);
                }
                holder.add(window, con);
                con.gridx = 0;
                con.gridy = SIZE+1;
                con.gridheight = 0;
                con.gridwidth = SIZE;
                holder.add(pan, con);
                holder.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                Minesweeper start = new Minesweeper();
                start.startGame();
        }
}
```

This is what is being shown:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvguY.png]

Comment: `JPanel p = new JPanel();` Do yourself (and the user) a favor. Make that `JButton p = new JButton();`. We can add an `ActionListener` to a button, and it will respond to both mouse clicks and keyboard actions. Buttons also support icons &/or text (useful for blank tiles, cleared tiles, mines or number of surrounding mines etc.)

Comment: I actually already wrote a panel class that uses jpanels. The goal is a minesweeper game, so I need to be able to manipulate them a little more.

Comment: *"so I need to be able to manipulate them a little more."* How, specifically? I doubt there is anything a panel can do, that a button can't.

Comment: I am manipulating borders and colors, as well as what is on the panel on a very exact scale.  I'm sure I could use buttons, but my panel method works just as well.

Comment: @acn3, You can manipulate Borders and Colors on a JButton as well. And a button already implements `getPreferredSize()` to you don't need to add that code.

Answer (score 1):

```
con.gridy = SIZE+1;
```

You can't specify a gridy value of 8. There are only two components added to the grid. The grid doesn't know that one of your panels happens to contain 7 rows of components. So the value should be 1.

This won't solve the problem but should clear up a misunderstanding of how GridBagLayout works.

```
holder.setSize(450, 450);
```

You are manually setting a size to the frame. Each component is originally sized at its preferred size. When there is extra space in the frame the space is distributed equally between the two components.

You should NOT be setting the size. Each component should determine its own size and then you should use `pack()`.  So you need to use custom components that override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the appropriate size for each component so pack() can do its job.

Also, the `pack()` is done just before the `setVisible()`.

Comment: So with the getPreferredSize() thing, you are saying that I just need to make each JPanel an object of a class Panel that has a method called getPreferredSize()?